# IIS6 cannot add new web site on Windows XP virtual PC

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have a developing machine in Windows 7 that has a virtual machine Windows XP Mode with Windows XP professional version 2002 Sevice Pack 3. I installed visual studio environments and IIS6 into virtual, but when I open IIS manager, I can see a default web site and I cannot add a new web site due to I need two web sites with different ports. I need to do it here, ¿How can I do it? As far as I know, with XP professional I can add new web sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIS on Windows XP cannot have multiple websites running at the same time and neither can you make additional websites from the IIS Manager.

Also, you are not running IIS 6. You are running IIS 5.1 if you are on XP.